# What is the most efficient way to append an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

Suppose you have two (numeric) arrays `$a` and `$b` and want to achieve what you get by doing

```
$a = & array_merge($a, $b);
```

efficiently.

Is this already the way to do it?
I find array_merge suspicious because it merges associative keys. Also I suppose the array is not updated but copied unnecessarily.
Is there a way to call array_push with an array?
Or would you do it in a loop with `$a[] = ...` assignments?

Comment: I am not aware of the intricacies in performance related to your question but if you wanted to run a few tests then I would recommend looping your theories 100K times and see which one takes the longest and/or consumes the most memory.

Comment: *"Also i suppose the array is not updated but copied unnecessarily."* That is not necessarily an issue. When an array grows, it will need some reallocation now and then.

Comment: `array_merge` will be your most efficient option

Comment: @cmorrissey If you could, please provide some benchmarks to your claim.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't `$a = & array_merge($a, $b);` means same as `$a = array_merge($a, $b);` ?

Comment: `array_merge` is compiled code which will make it faster then any loop you put in place

Comment: A lot will probably depend on your version of PHP, and maybe the environment you're running on; and if you try PHP7 or HHVM, the picture will likely change completely.

Comment: @cmorrissey It's not quite as simple as that, because PHP isn't just interpreted, it's compiled to an intermediate state, which can then be optimized by OpCache, HHVM's JIT engine, etc. So it's perfectly possible that the same processor instructions will be run for both cases. And the  majority of the overhead will be in memory  management,  maintaining the internal representation of the array, etc

Comment: @IMSoP okay I will agree with you on that, but in most use cases using the native function instead of rolling your own solution `should` result in more efficient results be it memory usage or speed of execution. In addition the OP should be benchmarking their own code this is a simple thing to run it would have taken less time then us batting it back and forth.

Comment: @Viral as far as I'm concerned no. assume `$a` was initially set by `$a = & $Obj->a;` - then it makes a difference.

Comment: @IARI Sorry, I've written this comment 3 times, but I was right first time: `array_merge` doesn't return by reference, so it makes no difference: http://3v4l.org/0HqWL

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` will reindex keys. To maintain keys, use `$c = $array1 + $array2`. If `$array2` has an existing key, it will be ignored. You can also `array_push`, `array_pop`, `array_shift`, and `array_unshift` for item addition and subtraction.

Comment: Just one note about `array_push()`; on http://phpfiddle.org/ (PHP v5.4.38) it takes 60% more time to complete 900,000 iterations of `array_push($a, '');` compared to simply calling `$a[] = '';`...for anyone wondering why I did 900,000 iterations, it is because the memory was exhausted when I tried 1,000,000